# Same namespace in multiple assemblies is a good practice?

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a single namespace spread across multiple assemblies. Resharper warnings that the namespace does not correspond to the file location.

Is it a bad practice? Is it better to use namespace that correspond with the file location?

In my specific case, I have two assemblies: an Portable Class Library shared by some platforms and then a specific assembly for each platform (UWP, Desktop, ...)

The namespace is MyCompany.I18N and it is dedicated to localization services.

Most of code is in the PCL but I need to write some code that is platform specific.

In the UWP case, I need to use XAML functions, so I created a UWP assembly. I thought that MyCompany.I18N namespace would be ok because it is an extension of the original I18N namespace but Resharper consider that it is not a good style.

Would I need to move to MyCompany.XAML.I18N namespace?  It seems more confusing for me. Which is the usual practice in these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very common convention that the layout of your files matches the namespaces in your code. This keeps things logically separated by folders and namespaces. ReSharper makes use of this by warning you when this doesn't match - it's usually an indication that the namespace is incorrect, or that the file is in the wrong place.

It's perfectly fine not to follow the convention if it doesn't fit for you. You can disable the warnings by changing the inspection severity in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> menu and setting it to "Do not show" (you can even save this to the Team Shared settings and check it into source control, and apply it on a solution by solution basis).

Also, you can disable it for specific folders. In Visual Studio, select a folder in Solution Explorer, then right click and show Properties. Then change the "Namespace Provider" setting to `false`. ReSharper won't treat that folder as being a part of the expected namespace. More details in the [help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/CheckNamespace.html).